# How to print data from left to right in html using css

Tags: html, css

Its a very basic question of css, but since i am new to css, i am not able to do it.
I have an html like

```
  <div>
    DATA1
  </div>

  <div>
    DATA2
  </div>


  <div>
    DATA3
  </div>

  <div>
    DATA4
  </div>
```

by default it print like this in browser

```
DATA1 
DATA2
DATA3
DATA4
```

but i want to print it in left to right order.

```
DATA1     DATA2     DATA3     DATA4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `float`.

```css
div{
  float:left;
  margin-right:5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  DATA1
</div>

<div>
  DATA2
</div>


<div>
  DATA3
</div>

<div>
  DATA4
</div>
```

or you can use `display:inline-block;`

```css
div{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
  
}
```

```html
<div>
  DATA1
</div>

<div>
  DATA2
</div>


<div>
  DATA3
</div>

<div>
  DATA4
</div>
```

and you can also use `flex`.

```css
div {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}
div>div{
  -webkit-flex: 1;  /* Safari 6.1+ */
  -ms-flex: 1;  /* IE 10 */    
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    DATA1
  </div>

  <div>
    DATA2
  </div>


  <div>
    DATA3
  </div>

  <div>
    DATA4
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm just going to add another way to do this, the methods posted by @mmativ are perfectly valid. The other way is using **table** and **table-cell**.

I addded a main class `data` and gave it `display:table`. The `cell` class was given `display:table-cell`

**HTML & CSS**

```css
.data{
  display:table;
}

.cell{
  display:table-cell;
  padding-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="data">

  <div class="cell">
    DATA1 
  </div>

  <div class="cell">
    DATA2 
  </div>


  <div class="cell">
    DATA3 
  </div>

  <div class="cell">
    DATA4 
  </div>
  
  
</div>
```